# Blender 2.8 not showing objects in render view (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Eevee works Ok and I can cut and paste into 2.79 and this displays in render view OK too? At the start of the project all was fine.  (It will generate a render OK)

[image]

Comment: Do you have materials applied? Are there any errors displayed on the console?

Comment: thanks for the reply...Yes materials are applied, including environment map background,  and everything was working OK.  Not aware of any errors showing - displays OK with Eevee.

Comment: Can you go to the outliner filter dropdown and select all restriction toggles?. Is there an indirect only filter applied to the collection (arrow icon next to the collection is bright white)?

Answer (score 3):

You've accidentally paused the rendering. Click on the pause icon to update the view.

[image]

Comment: Can't believe that after all these year I still forget to check that first, before searching for  more complicated reasons.

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue for me. Says ["Rendering done"](https://imgur.com/a/aNwDOwR) but what I'm looking at is nothing like a Cycles render.