# Cycles viewport render blank

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, image, eevee-render-engine

Hi so I'm completely lost on why this is happening in my viewport render in cycles but the image comes out completely grey. I've tried about every setting I can find and through these posts [Render result is completely blank?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53632/render-result-is-completely-blank), [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) but nothing seems to fix it. The weird thing is that this only happens in the rendered viewport shading. Not in look dev or solid in cycles, nor in EEVEE. [image] Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that you haven't paused viewport rendering?  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146134/blender-2-8-not-showing-objects-in-render-view-cycles/146148#146148

Comment: @RobertGützkow This is not about the _Rendered_ preview in the _3D Viewport_, it's the render result from _View_ > _Viewport Render Image_.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and here is what I discovered: Under 'Properties > Output properties > Dimensions' I accidentally had the option 'Render region' checked. Once I unchecked this option, Cycles was back in bussiness. A simple solution but it can be very confusing if you don't know what's going on, since Eevee would render with this option checked. Hope some day this helps someone out there.

Comment: The _Viewport Render Image_ rendering doesn't use Cycles.

Answer (score -1):

If it's not the *Render Region* like Mark suggested, maybe your *3D Viewport* is in *Rendered* preview mode? *Viewport Render Image* only renders the viewport as you see it when it's in *Wireframe*, *Solid* or *Material Preview* mode (when using the *Cycles* render engine).

**//EDIT:** Oh, you wrote it in the question you're in *Rendered* preview... yes, it is not supposed to render "real" renders, because it is supposed to do quick preview renders. From the manual: *"Solid mode uses the render settings of Workbench; Material Preview mode uses the render settings of Eevee."*

So, if you are using the *Eevee* render engine, it works in *Rendered* view, and if you are using the *Cycles* engine, it would be no quick preview anymore presumably.