# Cycles render is blank in viewport render for previews

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, shaders

I think I have the same problem as here [Cycles viewport render blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147035/cycles-viewport-render-blank)
The rendered preview in cycles does not work. The display in material mode works fine but not in shading mode. And everything works in Eevee. If I render my animation with cycles, it's very slow but it does work too. It only doesn't work in the viewport preview. But it did work before I messed with the output and render settings. I tried to get the settings as they were before but I still can't see anything in the cycles render preview (shading mode).
I don't know what else I could try. Maybe someone has some tips? "Render region" was already unchecked.

[image: blank objects]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ***paused*** your **<kbd>render preview</kbd>**.

Simply ***resume*** it to view it again.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That was such an easy fix and it worked

Comment: @yuka if the answer solved your problem, kindly consider accepting it by clicking the checkbox on the top left of the answer.