# Cycles render not working in viewport render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

After the 2.82 update, Cycles render isn't working in viewport and render tab. In viewport, it looks all white and flickers grey when I move my mouse, in rendering tab, it's always blank but when I save it as image, the output is fine.

I have tried following solutions

1. [Cycles viewport render blank](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147035/cycles-viewport-render-blank)
2. [Blender 2.8 not showing objects in render view (cycles)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146134/blender-2-8-not-showing-objects-in-render-view-cycles)

How my Viewport & render are looking

[image]

[image]

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: This might be an issue with your graphics driver. Have you tried updating it?

Comment: graphics card issue? or something for bug report? check if someone did not report it already in similar https://developer.blender.org

Comment: @RobertGützkow Yes, just realized there is an update pending for Nvidia. Will let you know if that changes anything. Thanks.

Comment: @vklidu Updating drivers right now, Will see if that solves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @vklidu Updating drivers didn't work.. the problem is still there.

Comment: @RobertGützkow, Updating drivers didn't work.. the problem is still there.

Comment: This seems like an issue that should be reported on the bug tracker (*Help > Report a Bug* in Blender) .

Comment: i have the same problem...

Comment: Double-check to see if Render Region is not active.

Comment: It is probably "Pause preview" a button next to rendered mode view.